# Why isn't my string array being sorted correctly in c++?

Tags: c++, string, sorting, selection-sort

Here is my code and output.

I essentially use selection sort as my algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void stringSort(string array[], int size)
{
    string temp;
    int minIndex;
    for(int count=0;count<size-1; count++)
    {
        minIndex=count;
        for(int index=count+1;index<size;index++)
        {
            if(array[index]<=array[minIndex])
            {
                minIndex = index;
            }
            temp = array[count];
            array[count] = array[minIndex];
            array[minIndex] = temp;

        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    string name[] =
    {  "Los Angeles ",  "Boise",  "Chicago",  "New Orleans",  "Calais",  "Boston",  "Duluth",  "Amarillo, TX "};

    int numberOfCities;

    numberOfCities = 8;

    int i;
    stringSort(name, numberOfCities);

    for (i =0; i<numberOfCities; i++) {
        cout<< name[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output in my Xcode

```
Amarillo, TX 
Boston
Boise
Calais
Duluth
Chicago
Los Angeles 
New Orleans
```

which is wrong because Chicago and Duluth should have been switched along with Boise + Boston. Everything else is fine. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the swap in every iteration of the inner loop. With selection sort, the goal is to loop though the remainder of the array to find the minimum, *then* swap. You should only swap at most once per iteration of the outer loop.

Instead try this:

```
for(int count=0;count<size-1; count++)
{
    minIndex=count;
    for(int index=count+1;index<size;index++)
    {
        if(array[index]<=array[minIndex])
        {
            minIndex = index;
        }
    }
    temp = array[count];
    array[count] = array[minIndex];
    array[minIndex] = temp;
}
```